# Directory of executables of ROS nodes compiled with Catkin

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have built ROS node that uses openCV and that needs to load some specific files during execution. The files need to be in the 'current directory' in [usual OpenCV implementation](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html?highlight=haarcascade), which I believe is the directory of the compiled ROS nodes.

- Is that correct?
- Where is it located?

The exact code I am talking about can be found on the link given above, where two files, "haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml" and "haarcascade_eye_tree_eyeglasses.xml" have to be loaded by the instructions

```
face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name )
eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name )
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200378/directory-of-executables-of-ros-nodes-compiled-with-catkin/) by [Alexandre.Willame](https://answers.ros.org/users/21108/alexandre.willame/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2015-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The executables are saved in the folder `<catkin_ws>/devel/lib` . However, if you wish to load some other files in your code (what you intent to do) this does not matter. I you use relative pathes for the file you load they need ot be somewhere relatively to your current working directory, i. e. the folder in which your call `rosrun` like `rosrun your_pkg your_node`. rosrun automatically locates your executables and runs them in the folder where you call rosrun.

Addition: If you use roslaunch your current working directory, i. e. the folder where your nodes run, will always be `<home>/.ros`, regardless where it is called....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could load using a path relative to your package.
http://wiki.ros.org/Packages#C.2B-.2B-

```
face_cascade.load( ros::package::getPath("some_package") + face_cascade_name );
```

---

Originally posted by [kmhallen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3102/kmhallen/) with karma: 1416 on 2015-01-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-01-05**:
The string returned by `getPath()` might not contain a trailing slash so watch out when concatenating it.